# Why is multiple imputation not used more widely in Data Science?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I have a background in statistics. Multiple imputation is very commonly used to handle missing data, and if it is not used it almost always results in serious criticism. Recently I have been interviewing for data scientist roles and so far none of the employers appear to use multiple imputation. A quick search for "multiple imputation" on this site resulted in only 27 matches !

Of course I understand that using MI requires more time and effort, but is that the only reason why ? For categorical data I can see the appeal of having a "missing" category, but what about numeric data? It appears that mean (or median) imputation is quite common in DS, but in statistics, this very much frowned upon since it is changing the distribution of the data often leading to bias.

Comment: I wonder whether this could be due to bias not being as much of a problem if your main task is prediction, not inference, and you condition your prediction being correct on being 'in-distirbution'. In this case spurious correlations are not a problem, and therefore certain kind of bias may be ignorable too.

Comment: @Cryo How is bias not a problem for prediction?

Comment: To your example at the end. Sure, imputing missing data with means, may distort the distribution of the data we would deduce from imputed data. So what, we define a new entity 'data+imputation_strategy' and build a model on this. As long as distribution of the underlying data, including the missingness mechanism do not change, we should be able to predict. But forget about discovery/inference

Comment: You're always able to predict. You don't even need data to predict: just predict `11` or `fish` every time. However, it seems like the bias could lead to poor predictions.

Comment: @Dale, if the distribution does not change, the combined distribution, the predictions would be ok, and if they do, then you re-train. That's the mantra I hear a lot in ML. Not a good way to build robust models, I agree. But this is my hypothesis why multiple imputation and things like causal analysis are not at the forefront (though some attention is given to them).

Comment: [Cross-posted at CrossValidated.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/637147/1352)

Comment: As you've cross-posted, and got a bigger response there, maybe you should close this question?